# How to form the proper query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to form a query for MySQL where it gets all the info from multiple tables but only displays the ones where the "activity" = "Other". Right now it is displaying everyones info and I don't know the proper way to format the WHERE part of the query. I want it to access the jobSearch table, read the activity and only return the ones where the activity is "Other"

```
$query_student = "  SELECT *
                    FROM student
                    JOIN major
                    ON student.studentID=major.studentID
                    JOIN jobSearch
                    ON major.studentID=jobSearch.studentID
                    WHERE jobSearch.activity == Other";
```

Answer (score 0):

You SQL syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column = value
```

In your case:

```
SELECT * FROM student ... WHERE jobSearch.activity = 'Other'
```

For reference, check this good tutorial about SQL syntax: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-where-clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL syntax is OK is not wrong

```
SELECT *
FROM student
JOIN major ON student.studentID=major.studentID
JOIN jobSearch ON major.studentID=jobSearch.studentID
WHERE jobSearch.activity = 'Other';
```

If jobsearch.activity field is a varchar use single quotes around the word Other and use only one "=".

Also I recommend using alias and not using "Select *", you might run into a problem because you have the same field name in different tables, try to use something like this.

```
SELECT st.*, mj.field1, mj.field2, js.activity, js.field2
FROM student st
JOIN major mj ON st.studentID=mj.studentID
JOIN jobSearch js ON mj.studentID=js.studentID
WHERE js.activity = 'Other';
```